# Get contents of external file and define as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to define a varible as the contents of an external text file?

**Example:**

```
function getfile() {
        var textfromfile = (contents of http://example.com/plain.txt);
}
```

*Plain.txt is one line and not particlaly long.*

Because I am using this for a chrome extension I am not allowed to use php - Is there an easy way to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an ajax call using jQuery and assign the response to the variable,

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "plain.txt",
    cache: false
  })
  .done(function( html ) {
    useIt(html);

  });

  //Useful to use variable after callback
  function useIt(variable) {
    alert(variable);
  }
```

Comment: Important note: this is asynchronous code. You cannot use `variable` right after this code, only inside the `done()` callback.

Comment: @Xan is there a way to use the var outside the done() callback?

Comment: @JBithell just declare a variable outside the callback I have edited the answer to show you

Comment: @JBithell see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @nmos reverted the downvote; to make the answer better, include a short remark on this (why is it important)